# Typescript: conditionally require parameter with type guard

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to better understand typeguards.  I think this is possible but I can't seem to get it working: if a parameter "foo" is true, then parameter "bar" is required to have a value.

Currently checking at runtime to accomplish the same thing:

```
function fn(foo: boolean, bar?: string) {
    if (foo == true && bar == undefined)
        throw new Error("if foo is true then bar can't be undefined")
}
```

I Thought TS would refuse to compile this, but it doesn't complain:

```
function fn<T extends boolean>(
    foo: T,
    bar: T extends true ? string : undefined
) {
    if (foo == true)
        bar.trim()
    else
        bar.trim() // compiler should error but doesn't
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you are not using `--strictNullChecks` you will never get an error for failing to check for `undefined`.  If you *are* using `--strictNullChecks` you should have [the opposite problem](https://tsplay.dev/WK7JDW) where the compiler is unable to verify that `bar` is ever not `undefined` by checking `foo` because generics+conditional types don't work that way, and even so, you can see by that call that it doesn't do what you want.  Closer to what you want is [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJRKgW) using a discriminated union.  Should I write any of this up as an answer?

Comment: That's an awesome solution thanks @jcalz for the explanation and typing up the sandbox.  Your solution looks great, just wish I could keep variable names without treating them like an array.  It sounds like what I'm trying to do isn't possible to do with Typescript, which is fine.  I'd also be happy to accept that as an answer.

Comment: Yes, [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nddg0N) is the closest I can get to something with variable names.  [This feature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#control-flow-analysis-of-aliased-conditions-and-discriminants) gets us part of the way there (with `foo`) but the part where `bar` comes along for the ride is not there yet.  I'll write something up when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want TypeScript to complain when you don't check for `undefined`, you have to enable [the `--strictNullChecks` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strictNullChecks), which is also included in [the `--strict` suite of compiler features](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict).  If you're not using `--strict` then you probably should, as it gives something like a "standard" or "recommended" level of type safety.

Right now you presumably have it disabled, which means the following is not an error:

```
const maybeString = (Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : undefined);
maybeString.toUpperCase(); // okay if --strictNullChecks is disabled
```

If you turn it on, you get the expected error:

```
maybeString.toUpperCase(); // error if --strictNullChecks is enabled
//~~~~~~~~~ <-- Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

So from here on, we'll just consider the case where it's enabled:

---

Your `fn()` function actually complains in both the `true` and `false` clauses of the `if` statement, even though it seems impossible that the `foo` could be `true` while `bar` is `undefined`:

```
function fn<T extends boolean>(
  foo: T,
  bar: T extends true ? string : undefined
) {
  if (foo == true)
    bar.trim() // unexpected error here
  else
    bar.trim() // error as expected
}
```

There's a general limitation of TypeScript where the compiler cannot really understand most implications of types that depend on an *unspecified* or *unresolved* [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter.  Inside the body of `fn()`, the type parameter `T` is unspecified.  It could be any type that `extends boolean`, and the compiler generally treats `T` either as just `boolean`, eagerly substituting `T` with its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints)); or, it has no idea what `T` is and can't see anything as assignable to it, lazily deferring evaluation of `T` entirely.  The type of `bar`, a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) involving `T`, is deferred this way.

It doesn't do reasoning like "what if `T` were `true` here, what if `T` were `false` here", where it evaluates each line of code multiple times for different possible narrowings of `T`.  It can't use [control flow anlaysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to narrow type parameters like `T`.  It mostly just gives up, as you've seen.

There are several open issues in GitHub about this sort of limitation; for example, [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) asks for some improvement to evaluating generic conditional types.  There's also [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) and [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) asking for a way to narrow type parameters.

If you look at some of those issues, it turns out that currently the compiler is correct to complain in your case.  The type `T` can be anything that `extends boolean`.  Now `boolean` is actually a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), a shorthand for `true | false`.  And while you might be expecting that means `T` must be *either* `true` *or* `false`, that's not true.  It can be any subtype of `boolean`, including the full `boolean` union itself.  And if `T` is `boolean`, then `foo` is `boolean` and `bar` is `string | undefined`, and any constraint you thought you were enforcing on the callers is not really there:

```
fn(
  Math.random() < 0.5,
  Math.random() < 0.5 ? "" : undefined
) // no error
```

The compiler happily accepts this call (since `T` is inferred as `boolean`), and there's a 25% chance that `foo` is `true` while `bar` is `undefined`.

For now there is no type safe solution to the above GitHub issues (often people will use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) and move on with their lives).  If you want type safety, we have to try a different approach.

---

Instead of using generics, we can try to use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), which is a supported way to check one property of an object (the *discriminant* property) to learn things about other properties of the same object.  If your `foo` and `bar` were properties of an object, then we could check `foo` to learn about `bar`.

It turns out that we can rewrite `fn()` as a function that takes a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) whose type is a discriminated union of [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions):

```
function fn(...args: [foo: true, bar: string] | [foo: false, bar: undefined]) {
  if (args[0] === true)
    args[1].trim() // okay
  else
    args[1].trim() // complains as expected
}
```

The implementation is fully type safe now.  Additionally, callers are forced to call it in one of the two supported ways and mix-and-match:

```
fn(true, ""); //okay
fn(false, undefined); // okay

fn(
  Math.random() < 0.5,
  Math.random() < 0.5 ? "" : undefined
) // complains as expected
```

As you saw, this isn't perfect.  It would be nice if you could just assign `args` to something like `[foo, bar]` like `const [foo, bar] = args` or `function fn(...[foo, bar]: [true, string] | [false, undefined])` or something.  But if you do that then `foo` and `bar` have been split apart into separate union-typed variables and the compiler loses the correlation between them.

[TypeScript 4.4 introduced a feature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#control-flow-analysis-of-aliased-conditions-and-discriminants) where you are allowed to first assign the discriminant `foo` to a separate variable and it will still work, so you can kind of get a bit closer:

```
function fn(...args: [foo: true, bar: string] | [foo: false, bar: undefined]) {
  const foo = args[0];
  if (foo === true) {
    args[1].trim() // okay
  } else {
    args[1].trim() // complains as expected
  }
}
```

But right now any attempt to do the same with `bar` will fail to work right:

```
function fn(...[foo, bar]: [foo: true, bar: string] | [foo: false, bar: undefined]) {
  if (foo === true) {
    bar.trim() // error again
  } else {
    bar.trim() // error
  }
}
```

It's possible that some upcoming TypeScript release will address this.  In [microsoft/TypeScript#44730](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44730), the pull request introducing this feature, it says:

> In particular, the pattern of destructuring a discriminant property and a payload property into two local variables and expecting a coupling between the two is not supported as the control flow analyzer doesn't "see" the connection. ... We may be able to support that pattern later, but likely not in this PR.

So there's some hope for improvement in the future.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=38&ssc=80&pln=38&pc=79#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-I-z0bLwRN0bU9e1fSdIDqHdW0vS4B0-TEANCQ-U49HDGBt13fdIA1NJjxWMkrhuKA7jAB4wCoQwUzTbAM2zXN82wbFm2ROR8QICtq1rPN60bFjixQ0MOxgKkXVASBYFzEgNVovsBx0F0aWfekh0ZJjmRE+VxOgItpLXMsFMhNlFWMecvAfBE9X6RtNPHDDwB09k9Nk6cDPldkN3QzC9wPXCtQI3VITPM8iITEikzAKIQFsai6G4-iy3outrxbEsSg4qsawY3i3yLVtjk-ZhhNEyElKk1SR3Uzs7I80zNzqUVGg1AhsMs6znFsoyi081V6hjF1gr0IA)